# Ember js animate insert

Tags: ember.js

I'll explain what I want to achieve first, and then what I tried.
I want to display 10 entries, and make an animation, so it won't just "appear" as a bulk, but to render one entry after the other. i.e. the first entry appears, then after 100 ms the second entry appears and so on.

What I tired, is give each entry object the css rule: "display:hidden", and then override the didInsertElement of the Entry View, and used jquery to fadeIn the element.
but that didn't help, it just delayed the rendering for **all** entries.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
var inserted = 0;

EntryView = Ember.View.extend({
   classNames : [ 'hide' ], // hide is display:none
   didInsertElement : function(){
       this._super();
       this.$().fadeIn( inserted * 100 );
       inserted++;
   }
})
```

So what happens here is that every entry added to the DOM is fading in (the value passed to fadeIn increases to make it seem like they are added one after the other)

But as I said, it's not working..
Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The job could be done in the `willInsertElement` handler</strike>.

***Update***

Well, I've updated the fiddle, using the didInsertElement (as you were doing), but adding the statement `this.$().hide()` at first. I think it's not ideal, but seems to work

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/bHL66/

***Update (bis)***

I think the proposed way in the question is the good one, and after some  thoughts, I wonder why this doesn't work... and in fact, it does ! Are you sure your css is defined right ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/mKvER/

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I was wondering to post this as a comment, as I think it could be an answer (this works). But yes, it's too short, I'm completing

Comment: sly7_7 thanks for the super fast replay! It does work when the array is already defined however, my array is fetched from the server. I changed the jsfiddle to apply my scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/bHL66/3/ As you can see, it is added as a block. no animation...

Comment: Thanks man! It's working! just a question though, why isn't it ideal? performance?

Comment: I don't exactly know, but yes perhaps it could blink on slow computers.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible for the DOM element to flash before hiding, since I've personally been doing jQuery effects this way. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/bHL66/7/) shows that the elements do not appear until after `.hide()` is called, at least for me. Does this prove that it's OK to assume nothing is shown before `didInsertElement` completes?

Comment: @pauldechov if you put a `debugger` statement before `.hide()` is call, you will see that the view is inserted. See the last update, for I think the cleanest way to do this.